# Changes are not getting reflected in Ionic 3 app even after successful build

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I met a problem for 3 days with my application ionic 3.
In fact, after builder in prod and release mode, it is always the old version that is always taken into account. the changes do not reflect.
So when mode debug, the changes are well taken.
 I tried several solutions may nothing.

Ionic v3

Also i have tried many solutions but no changes

1. ionic cordova platforms rm android
2. ionic cordova platforms add android
3. ionic cordova build android --prod --release --aot
   ------------no change-------------
   I have downgrade the app-scripts version always same

i have delete the www folder and run `ionic serve --lab` after i run build commande still no change

I need help.

Thanks you in advance

Ionic:

Ionic CLI          : 5.2.3 
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic 3.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 18 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.6.0
   native-run  : 0.2.8

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10

Build pass successfully

Comment: could you please let me know what changes are not reflecting in the app?

Comment: If i make change on scss, on html and .ts change are not reflecting

Comment: try using `ionic cordova prepare android` before you use the `build` or `run` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
The problem was related to the ionic plugin (appflow).

I had two choices
1. Generate the apk from the appflow platform with the configured branch.

2. Remove the ionic plugin applflow

I took the choice 1.

Documentation of appflow  https://ionicframework.com/appflow

Answer (score 2):

1. remove android platform using
2. `ionic cordova platform rm android` remove manually `node-modules` and
   `package-lock.json` (imp*)
3. Unistall old Application
4. `npm cache clean --force`
5. finally run `npm install`
6. `ionic cordova platform add android`
7. `ionic cordova build android`

Comment: Hi guys. @MD KHALI.

I followed the steps that you described but nothing to change. 
After the build in prod mode, the changes are not taken.
 On the other hand the build in debug mode is correct, the new changes are well in account.

Answer (score 1):

As @MD Khali said to remove the platform and add platform again, but if it happens after that you just need to click save 3-4 time. Because I have the same problem in my ionic 3 projects.

Comment: Finally I found the solution.
The problem was related to the ionic plugin (appflow).

I had two choices
1. Generate the apk from the appflow platform with the configured branch.

2. Remove the ionic plugin applflow

I took the choice 1.

Documentation of appflow  https://ionicframework.com/appflow