# Android no longer allows me to install app-debug

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, apk, failed-installation

I'm working on a ionic-angular application for android, eventually I had to build the apk to work with cordova assets that only would work once the application was compiled and ran in android (for reference, i have an android 5.1 samsung galaxy s5) an everything was working fine but every time i wanted to install the app an alert-like message would pop out saying that the application was unsafe and and that i shoudn´t install it so i would just tap install anyways and everything would work as intended, but today i accidentally tapped the 'ok' option in the alert and now i cant install the app and the alert wont popout anymore in subsequent attempts, it just shows 'installing...' to shortly after show 'App not installed'.

i already tried reseting my apps preferences, I have unknown sources on as it was before this happened, but still nothing, I've searched all over stackoverflow and it may be that i don't know exactly how to make a search query that shows me what I am searching for but everything I found about the problem is about apps in release that need to be signed or people that just never got the debug-app to work in the first place, do you guys have any idea of how to enable the installation once again?

Comment: From where do you open the APK (for example "My Files")?

Comment: @HB. I have a folder on my internal storage called 'dukto', there is where my apk is

Comment: How do you access your internal storage? Through "My Files" / "File Explorer" or what?

Comment: @HB. "My files".

Comment: Then go to - `Settings` - `Apps` - `My Files` and make sure `Install Unknown App` are set to allowed. By pressing `Ok` you have disabled this

Comment: @HB. I dont have that option, I went to both phone settings and My Files settings just in case but nope, i dont have that option

Comment: try this answer, you get result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237104/changes-are-not-getting-reflected-in-ionic-3-app-even-after-successful-build/57247151#57247151

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:
1. Uninstall the older version of the app from your device.
2. Turn off anti virus protection in your pc for some time.
3. clean your project
4. rebuild
5. try installing once again.
6. Enable the anti virus protection later on

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can activate the "Developer options" on your android phone. In this way, you can connect your phone to your computer with USB and simply run the command `ionic cordova run android`. This automatically removes the older version from your device and install the new unsigned APK.

Comment: I can´t sadly, my phone micro usb port does not work properly